# Changing bootstrap glyphicon onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to swap .glyphicon-menu-down to glyphicon-menu-up when user click on the link. What am I doing wrong? It's not working. Am I miss-using jquery?

**Markup**

```
  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
              Admin
                <span class="panelarrow glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down pull-right"></span></a>
```

**Script**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('.panelarrow').click(function(){
    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-down').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-up');
});
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `$(this)` refers to `.panelarrow` and you are trying to `find` `span` element inside that `.panelarrow`.

Solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.panelarrow').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-down').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-up');
  });
});
```

Or if you want to change your icon by clicking on the `a` element use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(){
    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-down').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-up');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the span (which includes the glyphicon) will let you use "this" to refer to the span - then the toggle classes can be included in the one command:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.panelarrow').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-down glyphicon-menu-up');
  });
});
```